# Remove \b in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, regex

I am parsing data via jSON where I am getting a special character(occasionally) `\b`, that is being fetched from the database and sent as jSON response. The fetched  data is shown in `ListView` but the data is shown as `DemoData[]`(something like this).

I have few issues regarding the `\b` character,

1. Is `DemoData[]` & `DemoData` same ? **EDIT 1:-** It is not
2. How to remove the special character ? **EDIT 1:-** This issue has been resolved.

Please guide me for a more concrete solution since the special character appears occasionally.

Comment: Are you talking about the literal `\` and `b' or the escape sequence in regular expressions which is `\b`? Because you can't replace \b -- its zero width word boundary. Makes no sense: http://regex101.com/r/lJ2vS1.

Comment: `\b` can't be replaced ? Ok. Please can you answer the 1st question also ?

Comment: Is `\b` referring to backspace character (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)? Or are you referring to the sequence `\b` in the string? Either way, they can be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all your "\b" characters with ""

```
YourJsonString.replaceAll("\b", "");
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: '\' is an escape character itself.

Comment: you can also give two regular expression in replaceAll(regex1,regex2) to replace.Giving String will work also.

Comment: @Neurenor Please can you answer the 1st question also ?

Comment: in case of  DemoData[] is String then just writing 'DemoData' indicates whole String array and writing only DemoData[] doesn't have any meaning.if you write DemoData[particularIndex] then it shows the values at that particular index. DemoData[] is used only when declaring an array not after that.